# What happens to emailed notes when I go over my Evernote monthly limit?

Tags: evernote

I have an Evernote free account which has a 40 MB monthly limit. I'm using the feature that lets you email in notes at an `@evernote.com` account.

I know that if you are using a client and attempt to go past this limit, the note will simply not be synchronized, until your monthly limit resets. But, when you use the email feature, there is no client that can hold on to your note locally until your next cycle starts. The note doesn't exist anywhere (besides *maybe* your sent mailbox in your email client). It seems like you could potentially lose information if you aren't careful.

What happens if I send an email when I'm over this limit? What if the email itself is the thing that causes me to go over the limit (e.g. 39MB + 3MB email = 2MB over the limit)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you do lose information. Emailed notes and pictures aren't added and are lost if you've reached your monthly limit. Fortunately the premium membership isn't very expensive and I'm not certain a single human person would be capable of reaching the premium limits currently in place.

The information on their blog might also be helpful: http://blog.evernote.com/2008/06/14/monthly-upload-allowance/

Comment: Did you try it out yourself, or did you read it somewhere?

Comment: I've text messaged pictures that were lost because I was already over the limit. I haven't tried emails but I'm assuming it would work in the same way. From what I understand, if the note isn't stored on your local Evernote client it is lost once you're over for the month.